# Как при нажатии на кнопку найти пост по id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть база данных которая создает профиль с данными людей, и при клике нужно что бы он выбивал нужный профиль по ID

это сыллки разных профелей которую вывел через `map`

```
{persons.map((person)=> {
                        return (
                         <div key={person.id} onClick={} className="friend">
                            <div className="circleOnlineFriend"></div>
                            <div className="avaFriend">
                                <img className="imgAva" src={person.img} alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="friendName">{person.firstName + " " + person.lastName}</div>
                        </div>
                        )   
                    })}
```

а это сам профиль который вызываеться и должен находить нужный профиль здесь я использовал `find` для поиска по ID нужного акаунта

```
const params = useParams();
const prodId = params.id;
const person = persons.find(p=>p.id == prodId);
return (
                <div className="fourth" >
                <div className="profile">
                    <img className="imgProfile" src={person.img} alt=""  />
                </div>
    
                <div className="profileTitle" data-aos="new-animation">
                    <div className="profileItem">
                        <div className="profileName">{person.firstName + " " + person.lastName}</div>
                        <div className="profileOnline"></div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="subTitleText">{person.proffesion}</div>
```

Comment: В onClick запихните функцию, которая должна принимать id и сохранять выбранное значение для рендера или в нужном вам компоненте. Вы не указали, как эти 2 компонента связаны между собой...

Comment: @SwaD спасибо за ответ , это мой самый главный вопрос как написать такую функцию которая должна принимать id , так как я новичок в реакте и вот начал изучению работу з базой данных.
Это два отдельных коспонента , хочу сделать по типу как в ВК когда нажимаешь в друзьях на человека , но не переходить по сылке на его профиль а выбить карточу с информацией, если сможете показать пример буду блогодарен

Comment: @SwaD сверху добавил фотографию моего проекта и цель

Comment: Понятнее не стало. Как эти 2 компонента(приведены не полные данные) взаимодействуют между собой. Если просто, на пальцах, передать ИД можно так: `onClick={() => clickFunction(person.id)}`, где `clickFunction` ваша функция, которая обрабатывает событие клика

Comment: @SwaD огромное спасибо , предстоит еще долгое погружение в мир програмирования)))